# Zksync USDC Events

Tags: ethers.js, usdc, zksync

I'm trying to interpret the tx
https://explorer.zksync.io/tx/0x97ab638ce8646f058c9fdafa1d30357a4ed9ecb2c5cb0976e60d897a425ffe83#eventlog

First log event's data value is `426912250000000`. The USDC contract has 6 decimals and this amount is `$426912250` is it true, do I interpret it right?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the transaction, the event was emitted by the contract at `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000800A`. It has nothing to do with `USDC`. It is an ERC20 token called "Ether" and it uses 18 decimansl.